# Convert or Import Cordova plugin into Native Android Studio Project

Tags: android

We currently have an existing cordova plugin. Is there a way to convert into or import into into a native android studio project?

Comment: No way..!. First you have create a cordova project using command prompt.

Comment: Then you have to add the platform -android.!!. then import your android native project

Comment: @stephin george do you means that its possible to import native android project to cordova but not possible to import cordova-plugin to AS project?